# Countries where in some parts of the territory they have a single official language different than the one spoken in the rest of the country?

Tags: policy, geopolitics, languages

Apart from Finland, Canada, India, South Africa, Denmark, Belgium and Switzerland, are there other countries where in some parts of the territory (like some kind of autonomous region) they have a single official language different than the one spoken in the rest of the country?

Concerning Finland, Åland Islands are an autonomous region of the country where the only official language is Swedish. In Canada there are zones where only French is official. Concerning Denmark, theoretically Greenland has Greenlandic as its only official language (although in practice almost everything is also translated into Danish). Then you have "multi-language" countries where there are multiple languages being spoken depending on the zone like India, South Africa, Belgium and Switzerland.

​
Are there any other countries where an autonomous region or some part of their territory they only have a single official language that is different than the one being spoken in the rest of the territory?

Comment: Small clarification.  *Federally,* English and French are always *official languages* in Canada.  However, the question is not wrong that French in Quebec is the dominant *provincial* language (and Quebecers are quite pushy about it, IMHO).  While the same can be said of English in the rest of the country (New Brunswick, IIRC is a special case).  Still, for example, in BC, you can ask for a trial in French and you can do English in a Quebec court https://educaloi.qc.ca/en/capsules/language-rights-in-court-in-quebec/  You could not ask for a trial in Mandarin in either province.

Comment: Switzerland does not have a language that could be said to be "the one spoken in the rest of the country."

Comment: I thought questions asking for open-ended lists weren't allowed, as being a bad fit for SE. Or does that rule not apply on Politics?

Answer (score 0):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

The languages of some historical national minorities are are legally protected (e.g. here for [Sorbian](https://revosax.sachsen.de/vorschrift_gesamt/3019.html), here for [Frisian](https://www.gesetze-rechtsprechung.sh.juris.de/bssh/document/jlr-FriesischGSH2004pAnlage-P2)), but this does not preclude the use of the German language for official purposes. In practice, some of the minority languages are in danger of going extinct. So some parts of the country have *additional* official languages, but they are **not** the single official language.